# Парсинг информации с сайта (числа)

Tags: python, парсер

Так как я изучаю Python, то решил от делать нечего написать простенький парсер статистики COVID-19 с одного сайта, но я столкнулся с проблемой, что я не могу спарсить числа(кол-во)
Вот ниже мой код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse():
    URL = 'https://coronavirus-monitor.ru/statistika/'
    HEADERS = {
        'User-Agent': '' #User-Agent у меня есть в коде.
    }

    response = requests.get(URL, headers = HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'total-table-row')
    comps = []

    for item in items:
        comps.append({
            'confirmed': item.find('div', class_ = 'value js-confirmed-value').get_text() #Ошибка тут
        })

    for comp in comps:
        print(comp['confirmed'])

parse()
```

[image]

То, я подчеркнул - я не могу спарсить, а то, что сверху, т.е классы "name violet", "name gray" и "name green" - я могу парсить.
В итоге, у меня выводится эта ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/User/Desktop/Парсинг/Parser.py", line 27, in <module>
    parse()
  File "c:/Users/User/Desktop/Парсинг/Parser.py", line 17, in parse
    'confirmed': item.find('div', class_ = 'value js-confirmed-value').get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Comment: конечно не сможете. Эти значения рассчитываются скриптом внутри. А сами цифры вытягиваются отдельным запросом.

Comment: И каким же запросом?

Comment: откройте консоль своего любимого браузера. посмотрите на все запросы. И Вы его увидите. Там прям чистый json - парси не хочу.

Comment: Не находится что-то.. Либо я не там ищу, либо не знаю, как он выглядит.
Я новичок.

Comment: а там нет суммы. там есть по каждой стране отдельно. Но разве это проблема просто просумировать в цикле все?